# find key words when keys are pressed

Tags: .net, algorithm, text-analysis

I am looking for a .net implementation of a text analyzer. The text analyzing should happen after each character is entered. the analyzer should be able to store several key phrases and fire an event whenever one of the phrases are entered. For example if the searched phrase is "Hello world" the analyzer should fire an event on "123Hello world" immediately after 'd' is typed, but it wont fire an event if "Helloworld" is typed.

Comment: Can you provide more details with example explained in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[binary trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) are your friends
and if it is not obvious enough - make a trie of all your options, follow the nodes on keyUp, when reached a leaf - fire an event.